# Display Admin menu only when in Admin area and authorized?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

In _Layout.cshtml, I have added Admin menu.

[image]

How can I make it displayed only when one is in Admin area and when one is authorized?

I did not try anything as I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to achieve it.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
   @{
        //get the value of Area
        var route = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"]?.ToString();
        var admin = "Admin";
        var result = Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        
    }

    
    @if (admin.Equals(route) && result )
    { 
        <div class="admin-menu">
            ......
        </div> 
    }

     <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

Demo:

check this simple demo, I use `Test!!!` as the menu, Only the one is authorized and in admin area can see this menu:

[image]